# UnicodeDecodeError occurring in one context but not in another, while the context itself seems irrelevant. Clarification?

Tags: python, string, unicode, codec, utf

I have the following code:

```
outlines = ""
foundnameslistlist = []
suggnameslistlist = []

filenames = []

fl = 0
flen = len(os.listdir(InputDir))
for filen in os.listdir(InputDir):
    if filen.endswith(".txt"):
        fl += 1
        foundnameslist = "\n*****************\n\n Names found--------\n"
        suggnameslist = "\n Names suggested--------\n"
        sourcefile = open(InputDir + '\\' + filen,'r')
        NLStrings = sourcefile.readlines()
        for NLS in NLStrings:
            ug = getunigrams(NLS.lower())
            nf = NField(ug, ndict, ncontextsdict, abscontextsdict)

            for fn in nf[0]:
                foundnameslist += "'" + fn[1] + "' in '" + ' '.join(fn[2]) + "'\n"
            for sn in nf[1]:
                suggnameslist += "'" + sn[1] + "' in '" + ' '.join(sn[2]) + "'\n"

        outlines += "File name: " + filen + foundnameslist + suggnameslist + "\n###################\n"

        foundnameslistlist.append(foundnameslist)
        suggnameslistlist.append(suggnameslist)

    if fl % 50 == 0:
        print(str(float(fl* 100)/flen) + "% of files completed.")
```

which produces the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\GNameHunt\NameFinderBeta.py", line 357, in ExecuteButtonClick
    NameExtract(InputButtonString.get(),OutputButtonString.get())
  File "F:\GNameHunt\NameFinderBeta.py", line 311, in NameExtract
    outlines += "File name: " + filen + foundnameslist + suggnameslist + "\n###################\n"
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 367: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The fact that I'm getting this error at all suggests to me that my mental model of how things work is flawed (i.e. why does it allow me to create the strings foundnameslist and suggnameslist without any special encoding without error and then suddenly fails when I concatenate them with outlines?  Clearly there must be something I'm not understanding).  Also of interest (and confusion) to me is that this code snippet DOES work in another context without producing any errors.  Here it's contained within a function accessed via TKinter GUI, but when I've run this snippet as part of a standalone script, no errors occur--even when the input for both instances is identical.

I've tried preemptively encoding every string in this snippet as utf-8, utf-16, and utf-32, all of which produce slightly different variations of the UnicodeDecodeError... and even worse; when I have it output the offending string for debugging purposes, some of the strings contain nothing but normal ascii characters--nothing weird at all, umlauts or otherwise.  The consistent thing is that it's always the same line that triggers the error: "outlines += ..."

Any insight you can provide here would be greatly appreciated.

Edit for clarification: using python 2.7

Edit 2: more context to follow

The function itself, entitled NFind, produces the correct output when called directly from the script.

```
sourcestring = os.getcwd() + "\\Matt Files"
NFind(sourcestring, "NameOutput.txt")
```

However, the relevant TKinter code:

```
    def IButtonClick():
        InputButtonString.set(askdirectory())

    def OButtonClick():
        OutputButtonString.set(askopenfilename())

    def ExecuteButtonClick():
        NFind(InputButtonString.get(),OutputButtonString.get())
```

produces the error after selecting the appropriate directory for input and appropriate file for output.

Out of curiosity, I put the following two lines at the beginning of NFind:

```
print InputDir
print OutputF
```

Calling NFind outside of TKinter (producing correct, error-free output), I get

```
F:\GNameHunt\Matt Files
NameOutput.txt
```

Whereas calling NFind inside of TKinter (producing the error), I get

```
F:/GNameHunt/Matt Files
F:/GNameHunt/NameOutput.txt
```

Comment: It might help to know how this code is being invoked in each context, since the context seems to be the source of the problem.  Once the difference is identified, it will be a lot easier to address.

Comment: The fact that the error occurs when called from Tkinter but not from a standalone script does suggest that the problem has to do with Tkinter. Somewhere or another, it needs strings to be ASCII (the most plain-vanilla 7-bit encoding), and it's encountering a string that isn't. The standalone script evidently does not contain a pathway where ASCII is absolutely required.

Comment: Incidentally, do not be too hard on yourself about your mental model when it comes to strings in Python 2. It is difficult-to-debug errors like this that helped motivate the design and implementation of strings in Python 3. The main thing you need to know (regardless of what programming language you're using) is to keep straight the difference between the platonic ideal of "string of characters" (a.k.a. Unicode) and actual encoded representations thereof (confusingly also often referred to as strings, but really ought to be called "sequences of bytes").

Comment: I added more context in the hope that the exact problem can be diagnosed.  Most of the time I've been pretty satisfied with Python 2, haven't had so many problems with string incompatibility issues until now.  That said, migrating to Python 3 is definitely sounding more appealing.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information. I don't think the slash-versus-backslash thing should make a difference; Python should be able to handle it. (And if anything, I would expect backslashes to be more likely to cause problems.) You can test by feeding `F:/GNameHunt/Matt Files` and `F:/GNameHunt/NameOutput.txt` into the non-Tkinter call and see if it still works. It should. Two more quick things: (1) At some point, the function apparently changed from `NameExtract` to `NFind`. This could be confusing for folks reading your question. (2) When debugging, instead of `print x` use `print repr(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest concatenating your strings using the python formatting tools instead of adding them together?

for example:

```
foundnameslist += "'{0}' in '{1}'\n".format(fn[1], ' '.join(fn[2])) 

outlines += "File name: {0}{1}{2}\n###################\n".format(filen.decode('utf8'), foundnameslist.decode('utf8'), suggnameslist.decode('utf8'))
```

The problem may also be in the list that you are joining. One of th eitems may be incompatible with the rest.

if the `utf8` does not work, try `latin1`

without seeing the contents of the file, it is hard to figure it out.

To help you debug:

```
try:
    outlines += "File name: {0}{1}{2}\n###################\n".format(filen.decode('utf8'), foundnameslist.decode('utf8'), suggnameslist.decode('utf8'))
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print(e)
    print(filen)
    print(foundnameslist)
    print(suggnameslist)
    continue
```

This will print out the error with the offending info t but will continue running

Checkout [pyformat](http://pyformat.info) - very helpful

Comment: I like the style of this, but I'm not sure I understand how the problem could be in the list that I'm joining as the error always occurs at the "output += ..." line and never before

Comment: well, based on the error, it thinks it is something other than ascii... I am ammending my code in the hopes that it is utf-8 and you are using python 2.6+ - I am adding the `u` in front of the strings the say that they are unicode.

Comment: Tried adding a u in front of all strings in my code, same error occurs.

Comment: which means it might likely not be a unicode character. by any chance, is this a file that originated on windows? it may have some funky double quotes

Answer (score 0):

I found that by adding the lines:

```
InputDir = InputDir.encode('utf-8')
OutputF = OutputF.encode('utf-8')
```

at the beginning of the NFind function, I was able to make it work properly.  Following John Y's advice and using print repr(x) instead of print x, I saw that when NFind was called via TKinter, InputDir and OutputF were unicode strings versus the default python strings.  .encode('utf-8') outputs the default string equivalents (counterintuitively for me, I'd have thought they'd convert from default to unicode rather than vice-versa.  More learning for me in the future).

It looks to be the case that the type of string for filenames and directories can change how those files are read, which I wouldn't have considered prior to this.

Thanks to all who contributed!